# ModuleNotFoundError in Python 3.7.3 Setup.py Package

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools, modulenotfounderror

I have a Python package in the format:

```
mypackage
├── README.md
├── doc
│   └── README.md
├── examples
│   └── README.md
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── core
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── main.py
    └── test
        └── README.md
```

It has an accompanying setup.py file:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup, find_packages


def read(fname):
    """
    Reads the README functions are prints them into the long_description in
    the setup routine.

    Parameters
    ----------
    fname : README file name

    Returns
    -------
    Rendered README

    """
    return open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), fname)).read()


classifiers = [
    "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
]

def run_setup():
    """
    This functions holds the setup command. Rather than running setup directly,
    it is wrapped in a 'try-except' that will print out errors if they occur.
    """
    setup(
        name='My Package',
        version='0.1',
        description='My package',
        long_description=read('README.md'),
        long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
        classifiers=classifiers,
        packages=['src', 'src.core'],
        python_requires='>=2.7.9',
        entry_points="""
        [console_scripts]
        my_package = src.core.main:main
        """,
    )


try:
    run_setup()
except SystemExit as e:
    print(e)
```

When I run `python setup.py develop` or `pip install -e .`, the package says it installs successfully. However, when I run `my_package`, it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/bin/my_package", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('My-Package', 'console_scripts', 'my_package')())
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/bin/my_package", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
    return next(matches).load()
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 105, in load
    module = import_module(match.group('module'))
  File "/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.core'
```

I have the `__init__.py` files in the appropriate places. I've tried using `setuptools`' explicit `find_packages` routine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please confirm that you have a package called `src` in your `site-packages` folder? You can run `pip list` to verify as well. I believe it installed the package correctly, but under `src` name - just want to verify.

Comment: Kacper, I do not see that there, but I do see My-Package.

Comment: Could you paste the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"` and tell how you invoke the `my_package` (when it gives the error)

Comment: Output: `/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`
With the `setup.py` written how it is, I am trying to call the system executable it creates. That is, directly, `$ my_package`

Comment: What happens if you run the `my_package`  which is located in  `/Users/mm/opt/anaconda3/<something>`, perhaps `/bin/`? I have windows and the folder is called `/Scripts/`.

Comment: Good idea. However... New development. I think this may be an Anaconda problem actually. I tried running it on another machine, with just the system Python, and it allows me to run `my_package` with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two things you can check. Often times, after doing check 1 your console script starts working. If not, try check 2 and see if it pinpoints you the problem.

#### Check 1: Correct python executable & pip combination

Sometimes the plain `pip install` installs using wrong `python` executable. Try to force the install with the same `python` executable as you are using when running the script.

```
python -m pip install -e .
```

To be even more sure, you can check your python executable path and use it directly in place of `python`:

```
python -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

#### Check 2: The code runs without the console script

Then, check that you can run the script directly. If not in the `src/core/main.py` already, add

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then, try to run the script directly with

```
python src/core/main.py
```

Comment: Check 1: No change.
Check 2: It runs directly.